# how to get only version number of a program? pipe into grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

```
rsync --version
```

gives lots of info but I just want to grab the first line

```
rsync  version 3.1.1
```

How to do this? I tried to pipe into grep but I can't

Comment: `read _ _ v _ < <(rsync --version); echo "$v"` works with my version of `rsync`. No need to use `grep`. Now I don't know whether it is guaranteed that the version message of utilities keep a consistent format (and hence can be parsed)…

Comment: What do you mean by "but I can't"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of ways to slice this pie.  If you want the whole first line, you can use any of these:

```
rsync --version | head -n 1
rsync --version | awk NR==1
rsync --version | sed -n 1p
rsync --version | grep '^rsync *version'
```

If you want just the version number without the rest of the line, that's not much harder, but it depends which part of the line you want. On my Mac, the version line reads `rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29`, and a naïve grab would likely yield the `29` - presumably not what you want. Either of the following will output just the `2.6.9` by itself:

```
rsync --version | awk 'NR==1 {print $3}'
rsync --version | sed -n '1s/^rsync *version \([0-9.]*\).*$/\1/p'
```

Comment: it works for rsync but none of them works for other program like pdfunite: pdfunite -v | head -n 1

Comment: It looks like `pdfunite -v` outputs to stderr instead of stdout.  `pdfunite -v 2>&1 | head -n 1`

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to get the first line of output use `head` command

```
 rsync --version | head -1
```